# Cucumber-CPP: All steps undefined in example

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, boost, cucumber, cucumber-cpp

I am following this [Cucumber-CPP](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp) github page to setup the framework. I have release version **v0.4**. Unfortunately, none of the step definitions get detected.

When I run **cmake --build build --target features** to check implementation against common cucumber test suite, I get the following result:

> [  3%] Performing update step for 'gtest'
>   
> [  7%] Performing configure step for 'gtest'-- gtest configure command succeeded.  See also /Users/xxxx/Downloads/cucumber-cpp/build/gmock/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-configure-*.log
>   
> [ 11%] Performing build step for 'gtest'-- gtest build command succeeded.  See also /Users/xxxx/Downloads/cucumber-cpp/build/gmock/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-build-*.log
>   
> [ 15%] No install step for 'gtest'
>   
> [ 19%] Completed 'gtest'
>   
> [ 30%] Built target gtest
>   
> [100%] Built target cucumber-cpp
>   UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
>
> **13 scenarios (13 undefined)**
>   
> **52 steps (52 undefined)**
>   
> **0m0.031s**

My environment:

> Ubuntu 15.04 64bit
>   
> Boost 1.55.0.2
>   
> Ruby 2.3.3
>   
> gcc 4.9.2
>   
> CppSpec latest dev
>   
> GoogleTest/Mock 1.7.0
>   
> aruba (0.14.2)
>   
> cucumber (2.4.0)
>   
> gherkin (4.0.0)
>   
> rspec (3.4.0)
>   
> multi_json (1.12.1)